# How do I enable touch gestures in Fedora MATE/GNOME/KDE?

Tags: fedora, gnome, kde, mate-desktop

Need to know how to enable touch gestures like multi-finger swipe to the next workspace...

Ubuntu has libinput-gestures, but how do I install that on Fedora?

All of the Copr repositories I have seen are years out of date..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**INSTALL:**

The following works for me in Fedora 29!

```bsh
# Install Requirements
sudo dnf install \
            xdotool \
            wmctrl \
            git

# Add Groups
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input
exec sg input newgrp $(id -gn)

# Add Multitouch Gestures
ORG_DIR=$PWD
cd /usr/src
sudo git clone https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures.git
cd libinput-gestures
sudo make install
libinput-gestures-setup autostart
libinput-gestures-setup start
cd $ORG_DIR
```

> ***NOTE:*** There should be no errors, if there are logging out and back in fixes the issue.

---

**CONFIGURATION:**

To configure the options copy `/etc/libinput-gestures.conf` to `~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf` and edit as needed.